# Spring Boot App not creating transactions when unsing Multiple datasources

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app with connections to a MySql and postgres database. The postgres is the primary and is set up exactly like the MySql example below but where you see mySql it is psql and the postgres beans are annotated with "@Primary" and "@EnableTransactionManagement" is added to the boot app main class.  The issue I have is that when the mysql beans are being used in what should be a transaction I get an error saying "Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress"
I am using spring boot 1.5.4 and hibernate 5.2.10

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;


@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "mySqlEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "mySqlTransactionManager",
    basePackages = { "mysql.dao" })
public class MySqlConfiguration {
    @Value("${mysql.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;

    @Bean(name = "mySqlTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager mySqlTransactionManager(@Named("mySqlEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager txMan = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txMan.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        txMan.setDataSource(mysqlDataSource());
        return txMan;
    }

    @Bean(name = "mySqlEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mySqlEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(mysqlDataSource()).packages("models", "mysql.entity")
                      .persistenceUnit("mysql").build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "mysqlDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mysql.datasource")
    public DataSource mysqlDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

The transactional method using javax.transaction.Transactional:

```
@Transactional
public void processRecords(Long id) {
    Record locked = recordsDao.findAndLock(id);
}
```

The Repository to retrieve the record

```
@Repository
public interface RecordsDao extends CrudRepository<Record, BigInteger> {
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Query(value = "select r from Record r where id = ?1")
    Record findAndLock(Long id);
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: It will only create a transaction for the default transaction manager you need to specify on the `@Transactional` with transaction manager (if not the default) it applies to. This means you cannot use the `javax.transaction.Transactional` annotation.

Comment: @M.Deinum is there a reason for this limitation?  This creates a problem for me since I am not in control of all of the service objects and repository objects or entities as they come from transitive dependencies that are scanned for at startup.

Comment: If you have 4 transactional resources you don't want to acquire all resources and start transactions for all of them even if you use one. Hence you. need to specify which one to use (if it isn't the default one).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for you input and insight, it was helpful.  As I said I do not have control over all the service layer classes that are creating transactions and therefore can not dictate that they call out a specific datasource that didn't exist when the service was written.  So I will have to find an alternate solution to my problem, most likely manually managing the transactions for both data sources.